# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.data'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, modulenotfounderror

I tried running this code:

```
from sklearn.data import load_iris
```

And it gave me the following response in my terminal:

```
    from sklearn.data import load_iris
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.data'
```

I am running this on python 3.7.7 in vscode. I already did 'pip install sklearn' in my terminal so I am not sure why it says there is "no module named 'sklearn.data'"

Answer (score 0):

it is `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris`

Answer (score 0):

There is no module named from sklearn.data.

The correct name is sklearn.datasets.

Try `from sklearn.datasets import load_iris`